# Flutter: I try to get api from backend with authorization bearer token in header using dio pack and http , i got Exception but is working in postman

Tags: flutter, api, http-headers, authorization, token

This is my code

```dart
Future<List<ContentHome>>getContentHome()async{
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('http://IPServerBackend/api/content/getAllContentHome/2?pgsize=10&pgnum=1'),
      // Send authorization headers to the backend.
    headers: {
      "Accept": 'application/json',,
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer MyToken",
    },
  );
  final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);

  return (responseJson as List).map(
    (e) => ContentHome.fromJson(e),
  ).toList();
}
```

The Exception:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected
```

How to solve this?

Comment: end of thid code you use two ',' char.
"Accept": 'application/json',,

Comment: It has nothing to do with it. I may have put it by mistake here while I put the code, but in my original code there are no two of them